# What is the difference between Execution Environment Description, Standard 1.1x VM and Standard VM

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

This scenario raised when I tried to update my JRE. I see below 3 options:

1) Execution Environment Description

2) Standard 1.1.x VM

3) Standard VM

What is the main difference between the above 3 and how does they effect?

Comment: How did you _"update your JRE"_? Where was an error message displayed? What was the _actual_ error message (copy/paste it into your post).

Comment: There was no error displayed but I see these 3 options when I wanted to Update my JRE in Eclipse through Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add (Here you will see the above 3 options).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to add say Java 1.6/1.7/1.8 then select Standard VM.
Standard 1.1.x VM is for as the name suggest for old 1.1 versions.
Execution Environment Description are symbolic representations of JREs e.g. you could define one for 1.7.x VM execution environment then the system could be configured to use a specific JRE to implement that execution environment e.g. 1.7.0_80.